# file() make copy(name destination) way to remove linked form and formulas

Tags: forms, file-copying

I'm trying to make a script to make a copy of a file, I used the makecopy(name,destination) formula and it worked like a charm however since the file I'm copying is the form destination folder, it creates a copy of the form, which I don't need and after a few days will start occupying space in my drive.

is there a way to prevent it from copying the form as well?

Comment: my first solution was to change the destination to a different location and then use a import range to get it into my original sheet, this worked well however when I make the copy of the file it also copied the formulas within which caused difficulties when I erased the form responses to prepare for a new day. having a way to make a copy of a sheet without formulas might also be a solution any ideas?

Comment: The file you copy is a folder? It creates a copy you don't need? Naively I'd say don't copy if you don't want a copy, could you clarify?